# Update base URL in my App if server changes

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection, nsurl, nsurlrequest

Suppose I am making a server call using NSURLRequest and NSURLConnection. I am making call to URL such as "http://www.testAAA.com.au/methodName". Now user installed my App. Few days later, I needed to change **base URL**. For example: "http://www.testAAA.com.au" to "http://www.testBBB.com.au".

In short, just base URL is being modified. I need to set such a mechanism that once server base URL changes, App can update base URL in the next call made for device. I have taken a constant for *base url*. So, next time the App makes any call to old base URL, I need to update that base URL with new one.

Is there any trick I can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have const NSString *baseURL; in your Constants.h file, then in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions you can set your baseURL with the new one, this will update the url when user restart the app.

Comment: But what if user launches App and later on URL has been modified ? At that point, every request will fail and will not work until user quits the App.

Comment: Yes,is it possible not to fail the request to the old url, but redirect the request to the new url in server?

Comment: Can u help me on how to redirect to new URL and how will I know when to do it ?

Comment: Actually I don't know, I think after you want to retire the old baseUrl, you can do the redirect.

Comment: Or you can check the app version, the new version use the new baseURL, if user is using the old version, remind him to download the new one.

Comment: That is right, I can do that. But question is that at what point I should remind user to upgrade App ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62650/discussion-between-pratik-and-carouselmin).

Comment: Use a push notification To modify the base url

Answer (score 0):

A common practise is to have a remote config endpoint that supplies a config file of some flavour (plist/json/whatever) that is downloaded at application launch.

1. Launch app.
2. Download remote config file.
3. Configure app with remote config.
4. Enjoy soft endpoint configuration.

It does rely on you having a constant config endpoint for any given app version but does mean you can change API endpoints at will.